# I m using visual studio code , angular and PostgreSQL..I want to connect angular with the PostgreSQL through web api..I have already created the UI

Tags: .net, postgresql

How to integrate all this three and how should I connect angular with PostgreSQL.I tried following many links but was unsuccessful in installing some packages .

Answer (score 0):

Break your problem down into steps:

1. Develop functionality to connect and query from .NET to PostgresSQL
2. Expose that functionality via a WebAPI controller
3. Call WebAPI service from Angular to retrieve data

Search the googel for an appropriate solution for each step and implement.